# Hide "Next / Previous" navigation if there's only one slide using jQuery Cycle2 plugin

Tags: jquery, css, api, slideshow, jquery-cycle

In the instance where there is only one slide in a slideshow, I would like to hide the "Next" control button (`.cycle-next`) which is being generated by the `data-cycle-next` attribute. I don't seem to have it working at the moment.

I have the following HTML (simply uncomment the `img` tags to test with different slide counts):

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" 
   data-cycle-timeout="0" 
   data-cycle-next=".cycle-next" 
   >
   <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
   <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />-->
   <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />-->
</div>
<div class="cycle-next">Next</div>
```

And my jQuery, based on the Cycle2 [API](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/api/):

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-initialized', function (e, opts, API) {
    if (opts.slideCount == 1) {
        $(".cycle-next").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/approach/MCWvA/3/) too.

Can anyone identify what the problem may be, or suggest another solution to use? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for? You could use the `length` attribute of the `div` element's `children` like this:

```
var slides = $('.cycle-slideshow').children().length;
if(slides <= 1) {
    $('.cycle-next').css("display", "none");
} else {
    $('.cycle-next').css("display", "visible");
}
$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-initialized', function (e, opts, API) {});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/MCWvA/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can find number of img with `.length` and then can hide next button.

[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MCWvA/5/)

Comment: This also works perfectly, but I saw @Bogieman's answer first and tested that. Many thanks nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative I used for a Cycle2 slideshow with divs:

```js
// flag slideshows with only a single slide by adding a "cycle-single" class
$('.cycle-slideshow').each(function( i ) { if( $(this).children('.cycle-slide').not('.cycle-sentinel').length <= 1 ) $(this).addClass('cycle-single'); });
```

This adds a `cycle-single` class to any `.cycle-slideshow` with only a single slide (or none). You can then do css rules based on `.cycle-slideshow.cycle-single` eg.

```css
.cycle-slideshow.cycle-single + .cycle-next {
  display: none;
}
```

in the OP case. As long as the syntax is consistent this should work fine for multiple sliders per page.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need add ID = slideshow to your code :

```
 <div id="slideshow" class="cycle-slideshow" 
       data-cycle-timeout="0" 
       data-cycle-next=".cycle-next" 
       >
       <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
       <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />-->
       <!--<img src="http://placehold.it/450x250" />-->
    </div>
    <div class="cycle-next">Next</div>
```

then use:

```
   $('#slideshow').on('cycle-initialized', function (e, opts) {
        if (opts.slideCount <= 1) {
            $(".cycle-next").css("opacity", 0);
        }
    });
```